# Remove element from arraylist on checking and then unchecking the checkbox of checkbox listview

Tags: java, android

I have one dynamic checkbox listview. On selecting multiple checkbox I got the right arraylist but when I checked two check boxes one by one and then unselect one it should take one checked box but it is taking previous selected two.

```
        rd_student.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String value=objects.get(position).getUserName();
                dbs=new DataBeanStudent();
                //is chkIos checked?
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    if (stringArray.contains(value)){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Already added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stringArray.add(value);
                        selectedStrings.add(value);
                        dbs.setUserName(value);
                        studentArray.add(dbs);
                        saveDataInSP(stringArray, finalV, studentArray);
                    }
                }else
                {
                    if (stringArray.contains(value)){
                        selectedStrings.remove(value);
                        stringArray.remove(value);
                        studentArray.remove(value);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Already Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

For arraylist I have one method `getSelectedString()` and I am not getting correct list after unselecting checkbox.

```
    ArrayList<String> getSelectedString(){
     return selectedStrings;
    }
```

Called `getSelectedString()` here in `saveDataInSP(ArrayList<String> stringArray, View view, ArrayList<DataBeanStudent> studentArray)`

```
  private void saveDataInSP(ArrayList<String> stringArray, View view, ArrayList<DataBeanStudent> studentArray)
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    JsonArray myCustomArray = gson.toJsonTree(stringArray).getAsJsonArray();
    JsonArray studentArray1 = gson.toJsonTree(studentArray).getAsJsonArray();

    stringArray = getSelectedString();
    Log.e("stringarray",stringArray.toString());
    String jsonText = gson.toJson(stringArray);

    sp_dairy = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_DAIRY, 0);
    se_dairy = sp_dairy.edit();
    se_dairy.clear();
    se_dairy.putString("dairy", ""+myCustomArray);
    se_dairy.putString("studentArray", ""+studentArray1);
    se_dairy.putString("string_array", ""+jsonText);
    se_dairy.commit();

}
```

Check with below image.

```
 ![Screenshot][1]
 ![Screenshot][2]
 ![Screenshot][3]
 ![Screenshot][4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use OnClickListener for Checkbox, use OnCheckedChangeListener.

```
rd_student.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            String value=objects.get(position).getUserName();
            dbs=new DataBeanStudent();
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (isChecked) {
                if (stringArray.contains(value)){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Already added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    stringArray.add(value);
                    selectedStrings.add(value);
                    dbs.setUserName(value);
                    studentArray.add(dbs);
                    saveDataInSP(stringArray, finalV, studentArray);
                }
            }else
            {
                if (stringArray.contains(value)){
                    selectedStrings.remove(value);
                    stringArray.remove(value);
                    studentArray.remove(value);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Already Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Also when we use a ListView or RecyclerView, the child views get recycled.
So, always include this in your adapter, after the above code. (Assuming the above code is also in the adapter.)

```
if(stringArray.contains(value))
    rd_student.setChecked(true);
else
    rd_student.setChecked(false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still my problem is same after unchecking the checkbox, it take its value.